# How to load data to radio buton and modify them with React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sql-server, express, radio-button

I am new to react and I have a problem with Express (database: MSSQL) and React.

I have this fictive [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K9bP.png), and I would like to visualize the data per person with radio buttons [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbrUq.png).

When I tried I could successfully load it to the frontend but I can't modify their values. I found a way, but it could only render the new value to checked with setChecked on the second click, but the radio button I clicked couldn't get selected.

datajs: I made this objectified array because I needed to use the sql column headers for easier attainability

Is there any better way to render data dynamically to the frontend?

Thanks in advance!

```
row.map((row) => (
  {data.map((data) => (
    <TableRow sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0, }, }} key={data.id} >
      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
        {data.name}
      </TableCell>
      {["C", "I"].map((option) => (
        <TableCell align="right">
          <input
            type="radio"
            name={data.radio}
            value={option}
            defaultChecked={
              row[data.sqlCol] === option
            }
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </TableCell>
      ))}
    </TableRow>
  ))}
```

```
  const data = datajs.map((item, index) => ({
    ...item,
    id: index + 1,
    radio: item.sqlCol,
  }));

const datajs= [
  {
    name: "Homework",
    sqlCol: "Homework_School",
  },
  {
    name: "Laundry",
    sqlCol: "Laundry_Home",
  },
]

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const updatedValue = { [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    const isAlreadyChecked = checked.some(
      (item) => Object.keys(item)[0] === e.target.name
    );
    if (isAlreadyChecked) {
      setChecked((prev) =>
        prev.map((item) =>
          Object.keys(item)[0] === e.target.name ? updatedValue : item
        )
      );
    } else {
      setChecked((prev) => [...prev, updatedValue]);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your **handleChange** function. TRY THIS and if you have any further questions then ask me

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setChecked((prevChecked) => ({
      ...prevChecked,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
```